# How to compile a program for distribution on Mac

Tags: macos, gcc, compilation, static-linking

I am developing a program on OSX 10.6.4 (Snow Leopard), and I want to be able to run the compiled product on other Intel Macs, some of whom may not have XCode isntalled.

To simplify things, I first wrote a Hello World program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile it as

```
gcc -static prog.c
```

I get the folllowing error:

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
```

I don't know where to find this library. Now, some people have mentioned that I should not compile statically on macs since the *system* shared libraries should be available everywhere (third party libraries can be manually linked). However, when I try to run this Hello World program on another mac, I get the folowing error:

```
 dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
 Trace/BPT trap
```

So, how do you compile a program on mac so that it can be distributed? I am not having architecture issues, as most computers I am interested in are Intel Macs.

Comment: You should not link statically because there are no static libraries on the mac. All the system libraries are *only* available in shared form. Your problem is probably something else.

Comment: Presume this is a pure-C Unix executable, rather than a GUI application??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `-static`. Your executable will run fine on other 10.6.x x86 Macs. If you want to deploy on pre-10.6 Macs then you'll need to use the appropriate SDK but apart from that it should "just work", regardless of whether the developer tools are installed.

Comment: I tried to compile as gcc prog.c -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk

However, it still givesdyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
Trace/BPT trap
on an older machine. Is this how one uses the SDK?

Comment: Ok so it works for the Hello world program after adding -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 to the gcc command line. However, for a C++ program it needs certain tr2 implementations introduced in 10.6, and it doesn't compile with that SDK. It compiles if I use the macports gcc, but then when running on another computer it fails to find a function in /ust/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib.

Comment: If you have a dependency on 10.6 then obviously your executable will not run on 10.5.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth using XCode to create your executable, using the Command Line program template (basic Unix executables), simply because it will manage a lot of the compiler options for you (including which SDK you are compiling against / which versions you are targeting).

My guess is that a default commmand-line compilation is going to compile against the current system libraries (10.6.4).